# Measuring similarity between two datasets

Tags: unsupervised-learning, similarities, overlapping-data, umap

This is quite straightforward:

I have a dataset with 8 features containing cell measurements from a patient. I want to compare two patients to a reference one. To do this I perform UMAP to reduce the 8 features to 2 (also because I cannot perform a feature-wise comparison; I don't think more details are needed here, let me know) and then plot the reference (blue) and on top of it I plot each patient (red). Below you can see the results.

Patient A:
[image: More similar]

Patient B:
[image: Less similar]

To me, the first patient is more similar to the reference than the one below. I think what I am looking at is the degree of superposition/overlay on the UMAP embedding (see comments). Is there a metric or a way to quantify this?

Thank you!!

Comment: "Clearly the first two patients are more similar than the ones below." Can you elaborate on what you mean by this?

Comment: Well I just mean that the overlap between the two colors is better than below. For example, in the second figure there are areas of the embedding in which we find only red points. In the first one, blue and red are more "perfectly mixed", so to speak. They are one on top of the other. Let me know if this clarifies the issue

Comment: So you mean that, taken over all of the red points, the distance to the closest blue point is larger?  Possibly by symmetry you'd like to do this from the perspective of the blue points as well?

Comment: I guess that could be a way. You mean to take the summation of closest distances? Actually, the blue points are a 'reference' so it should be enough with measuring one perspective. I have clarified this in the description of the issue.

Comment: Why do the blue points change from one plot to the next?  Aren't they supposed to be representing the same reference subject on the same axes?

Comment: Because I recomputed the UMAP embedding for each pair of patients.
In any case, I think this is not so important. I mean, regardless of how this was done, the question is whether there is a way to quantify the degree of overlap of two point clouds

Comment: Because the mappings are different, how is one supposed to compare them??

Comment: I want to compare within each plot. Let's say I compare red vs blue in the first one and get a "similarity score" of 0.8. Then I perform the same in the figure below (compare red vs blue) and get a similarity score of 0.7. I would conclude that the first one is more similar to the reference than the second one.